# Google OAuth 2.0 and debug key

Tags: google-oauth

Im trying to implement google OAuth 2.0 in android app.

According to google help - I went to console.developers.google.com to create project and Client ID for that project.

I have to put app package name and SHA-1 key there. I have no SHA-1 key for "release" version yet. I guess there is some automatically generated SHA1 key for debug. Application is not ready for publishing yet, so... I'm not using release builds.

1. Shall I use this debug key for now and when I release app - create new Client ID in google dev console?
2. Where I can find that SHA-1 key in Android Studio?

Answer (score 0):

I found answer:

> **Caution:** While you are testing an APK that's signed with a debug key, Google does not require that your app be registered in Google
>   Cloud Console. However, your app must be registered in Google Cloud
>   Console in order to continue working once it is signed with a release
>   key.

Source: [Authorizing with Google for REST APIs at developer.android.com](https://developer.android.com/google/auth/http-auth.html)

I don't have to add debug app in Google Developer Console / Google Cloud Console.